# how to convert varchar dataype to text in mssql database?

Tags: sql-server

i have table with data and now i want to change its column dataype from varchar to text,

```
  ALTER TABLE ver_table ALTER COLUMN field text;
```

unfortunately it gives the

```
SQL Error [1088] [S1000]: Cannot find the object "ver_table" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
  Cannot find the object "ver_table" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

but the table actualy exists with data.

The query should support in all versions of Sql server.
Is any other to achieve this without losing of  data, i mean any procedure ?

Please do correct me.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure table name is `table`??

Comment: no ..actually i made it temporary name..sorry my mistake

Comment: Either you have a typo in the table name or your account doesn't have alter permission on it

Comment: on the same instance i just made changes with other columns..but..it executed nicely..i have only problem with this particular query only..

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using the text data type.

> **Important**
>
> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types
>   in new development work, and plan to modify applications that
>   currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and
>   varbinary(max) instead.

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql).